# data.table non-join on one column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to do a join in data.table where within a set of columns that match another table I want all values in a third column from that table that don't exist in the initial table. Here's an example:

```
library(foreach)
library(data.table)

tmp <- data.table(mgr=c('1','1','1','1',
                        '2','2',
                        '3','3'),
                  year=rep(2022,8),
                  stocks=c('A','B','C','D',
                           'A','B',
                           'C','D'))
```

The input table looks like this:

```
   mgr year stocks
1:   1 2022      A
2:   1 2022      B
3:   1 2022      C
4:   1 2022      D
5:   2 2022      A
6:   2 2022      B
7:   3 2022      C
8:   3 2022      D
```

I then get all unique stock-year combinations. Then for each mgr-year I want the stocks that are not in `tmp` for that particular mgr-year pair:

```
allstocks <- unique(tmp[,.(year,stocks)])

myloop <- unique(tmp[,.(mgr,year)])

out <- foreach(myidx=1:nrow(myloop)) %do% {
    tmp1 <- tmp[myloop[myidx],on=.NATURAL]
    tmp1 <- allstocks[!tmp1,on=.(year,stocks)]
    tmp1 <- merge(myloop[myidx],tmp1,by=c('year'))
    tmp1
}

finalout <- rbindlist(out)

finalout
```

This gives:

```
   year mgr stocks
1: 2022   2      C
2: 2022   2      D
3: 2022   3      A
4: 2022   3      B
```

Since mgr 1 has all stocks there is no row for that manager. I'm also okay with there being a row with NA in stocks for that particular mgr-year.

Effectively what I want is for each stock-year to obtain a list of the stocks that each mgr does not hold. This example works, but the actual data is ~100mm rows so I'm wondering is there is a way to do this with pure data.table in an efficient manner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `data.table` there is a `!` operator for exclusions.

```
setkey(tmp, mgr, year, stocks)
all.stocks <- tmp[, .(stocks=unique(tmp$stocks)), by=.(mgr, year)]
setkey(all.stocks, mgr, year, stocks)
missing <- all.stocks[!tmp]
```

This should be pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely the cleanest way to do this. I was implicitly avoiding constructing all.stocks as you did since I thought it was going to be very large (ends up only being 130mm rows). Just tried it on my full data and it works very well.

Comment: How fast was it, if you don't mind my asking?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is a "one-liner" which uses

- *cross join* `CJ()` to create all unique possible combinations of `mgr`, `year`, and `stocks`,
- the *exclusive join operator* `!`,
- the `on =` clause to indicate the columns to join on,
- data.table *chaining*:

```
tmp[, CJ(mgr, year, stocks, unique = TRUE)][!tmp, on  = .(mgr, year, stocks)]
```

> ```
> Key: <mgr, year, stocks>
>       mgr  year stocks
>    <char> <num> <char>
> 1:      2  2022      C
> 2:      2  2022      D
> 3:      3  2022      A
> 4:      3  2022      B
> ```

Note that it is *not* necessary to call `setkey()` explicitely as the default parameter `sorted = TRUE` of `CJ()` already sets keys and `on` uses these.